# Bring back Sonarqube (5.2) war deployment?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, war, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

In the 'old' days one could choose to install sonarqube as standalone installation or as WAR to a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty.

(We are currently integrating our VSO build environment with Sonarqube and Azure using msbuild runner.)

In this (cloud) technology stack, we need/want to deploy sonarqube to the azure cloud. Since it can only be installed as standalone instance I need to instantiate and manage a complete Azure VM instance.
If SonarQube could be installed as WAR, I would be able to deploy it as Azure Web app, which is much more effective (cost, maintenance, ...).

Are there plans with SonarQube to bring back WAR deployments?

Comment: This question about roadmap is not really suitable for StackOverflow. Please reach out to google group : sonarqube@googlegroups.com next time to allow discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: there's *currently* no plan to bring back WAR deployments.

Long answer: as we have a partnership with Microsoft (as you might have seen over the past months), this is a need that we are aware of and that might get back on the table some day.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic requirement is to host SonarQube in Azure Websites.

Azure Web Apps support deployment of [custom Java apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/). It leverages the httpPlatformHandler module in IIS to achieve the same.

The steps are as follows -

1. Copy the SonarQube windows-x64 package to the `wwwroot` in the web app
2. Deploy a web.config at this root with in the following format

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
         <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
       </handlers>
       <httpPlatform processPath="%HOME%\site\wwwroot\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat">
         <environmentVariables>
           <environmentVariable name="HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
           <environmentVariable name="JAVA_HOME" value="%JAVA_HOME%" />
         </environmentVariables>
       </httpPlatform>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```
3. Configure `sonar.web.port` (in `sonar.properties`) to `${env:HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT}`. This is necessary because Azure Web Apps assign random port at every start. The environment variable is being set in `web.config` shown above.